# OSGi - modify a class in a bundle without modifying the original bundle

Tags: osgi, equinox, osgi-bundle

I have a need to modify a class in a OSGi bundle. But this bundle comes from an upstream project hence I cannot(/won't) touch it. But I have to modify a class in it to match my project's requirements. So, I'm looking for a solution for this.

So, I created my own bundle which has the patched classes. But there is a complication since the upstream OSGi bundle, and the patch OSGi bundle I created has the same packages. I want to over-ride the classes in the upstream OSGi bundle, without touching the it.

I looked at the [osgi.org Fragment](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Fragment) page. It suggests a way to patch a host bundle by using a fragment bundle, but for that I have to modify the upstream project bundle's `MANIFEST.MF` to set `Bundle-ClassPath: patch.jar,.`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a [WeavingHook](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/hooks/weaving/WeavingHook.html) and catch the class loading of that bundle.

However, do it only if you do not have any other chance to solve your problem. If you have any chance to contribute to that project that contains the jar, send a patch for them and have this only as a temporary solution. With hacks like this, your system will be chaotic for others.

Comment: Yes. The original question boils down to: I want to change something without actually changing it. This is just not a reasonable thing. Either change it or don't. Using a weaving hook can be used at runtime to replace the class but that also has its risks.

Comment: Contributing back to the project doesn't going to work in this case since it's a custom change. I will try with a Weaving Hook. I know weaving hooks play with classloaders, but what are the risks?

Comment: @user3580...: Imagine that you are a colleague of yours who gets your code to continue the development. Imagine that you cannot talk to yourself about the trick you applied. How will you find out where to fix a bug, debug and improve the code. The solution that is clear to you, might be magical for others. Many of the projects are dropped away due to the reason that there are too many tricky solution in them and nobody else understands the code, only the one who wrote it. That is why I suggest to think of this as a temporary solution if you have no other options.

Comment: If it's a custom change, then think of a way to make the original library more abstract or extensible. That way you can apply your custom change without hacks, and others can make their own custom changes.